# Component library created with React, Typescript and Rollup. Importing a component adds CSS from ALL other components into <head>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, rollup

I've created a React Component library using Typescript and Rollup and I'm encountering a problem when using it in another application. Whenever I import a single component like so:

`import { Button } from "@company/component-library";`

Then the CSS files of ALL other components are included in the `<head>` tags of the app. See screenshot:

[image]

However, if I import it as follows:

`import { Button } from "@company/component-library/dist/components/Button/Button";`

It correctly adds only 2 CSS files in the `<head>` as it should.

[image]

How can I make sure that the same happens when I use the first version? Currently my Rollup config looks like this:

```
import peerDepsExternal from "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external";
import resolve from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import typescript from "@rollup/plugin-typescript";
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import { terser } from "rollup-plugin-terser";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";

const postcssOptions = () => ({
  extensions: [".scss", ".css"],
  use: ["sass"],
  modules: true
});

export default {
  input: "src/index.ts",
  output: [
    {
      dir: "dist",
      format: "esm",
      preserveModules: true,
      sourcemap: true,
      exports: "named"
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    peerDepsExternal(),
    postcss(postcssOptions()),
    typescript(),
    commonjs(),
    resolve({ extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".tsx"] }),
    terser(),
    json(),
    {
      name: "Replace node_modules with dependency",

      generateBundle: (options, bundle) => {
        Object.entries(bundle).forEach(entry => {
          // Replace the node_modules/style-inject reference with the style-inject package dependency.
          if (entry[0].match(/.*(.scss.js)$/)) {
            bundle[entry[0]].code = entry[1].code.replace(
              /(\.\.\/|\.\/){1,5}node_modules\/style-inject\/dist\/style-inject\.es\.js/,
              "style-inject"
            );
            return;
          }

          if (entry[0].match(/.*(.js)$/)) {
            // Replace the node_modules/tslib reference with the tslib package dependency.
            bundle[entry[0]].code = entry[1].code.replace(
              /(\.\.\/|\.\/){1,5}node_modules\/tslib\/tslib.es6.js/,
              "tslib"
            );
            return;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  ],
  external: ["react", "react-dom"]
};
```

Thanks in advance for your help.